# applicationDidEnterBackground not called when app screen goes off

Tags: ios, appdelegate

**AppDelegate.m**

```
 - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [ScreenState setScreenState:FALSE];
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [ScreenState setScreenState:FALSE];
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [ScreenState setScreenState:FALSE];
}
```

When I press the **Home** button or the **Standby** button, the above code gets triggered, enabling my hackish "ScreenState" static class to monitor whether the screen is active or not.

**However,** when I don't press anything, the screen shuts down after a few minutes and the above functions do not get called, enabling a very annoying bug to appear to my users...

Anyone has an idea?? This app needs to be in the App Store, so no hacks!

Comment: What iOS version are you using?  Do you get the same results if you create a simple test program and log a message from `applicationDidEnterBackground:`?  (Hint: I'm seeing a background callback in that circumstance.)

Comment: @PhillipMills it's 8.1.3. In XCode, minimum compile version is 8.0. I cannot use NSLog because when the iPhone is connected to the debugger, the screen stays on! Only when disconnecting the screen goes off...

Comment: NSLog should write to the device log when you are disconnected from Xcode...which you can then read when you reconnect.

Comment: @PhillipMills Could you please elaborate on that further. I do not understand. When I hit the big square "Stop" button, screen goes off in 3 minutes. BUT when I hit the "Play" button, app gets rebuild and run, so it starts all over again, it doesn't resume!